# User Popover avatar img element in chat has no alt text for users

Tags: bug, chat, images, profile-picture, accessibility

I was trying to figure out what hat [smokie](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/120914/smokedetector) was wearing, and I noticed one of the instances of the chat avatar is missing any alt text.

I've snipped out the svg source for the hats, so you'll have to imagine them instead of read those bits. I've also snipped out other unrelated chunks but kept the structure.

Below is the code for my avatar next to the text box in chat:

```html
    <td rowspan="2" width="64">
      <div id="active-user" class="user-container user-28560">
        <div class="hat" style="float: left; display: block; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: visible; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -1px;" data-hatid="75483903"><img style="display: block;" src="data:image/svg+xml,<snip>"
            width="65" height="96"></div>
        <div class="avatar user-gravatar64">
          <img height="64" width="64" title="AncientSwordRage" alt="AncientSwordRage" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6de7362951ec5bf3d40fa02de7175552?s=64&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" srcset="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6de7362951ec5bf3d40fa02de7175552?s=128&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG 2x"
            style="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div title="You have a reply/mention" id="reply-count" style="visibility: visible; display: none;"></div>
      <snip>
    </td>
```

And here is the equivalent html for my avatar next to one of messages:

```html
    <div class="user-container user-28560 monologue mine">
      <a href="/users/28560" class="signature user-28560">
        <div class="hat" style="float: left; display: block; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: visible; position: relative; left: 26px; top: 0px;" data-hatid="75483903"><img src="data:image/svg+xml,<snip>"
            width="16" height="24" style="display: block;"></div>
        <div class="tiny-signature" style="">
          <div class="avatar avatar-16"><img width="16" height="16" src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/6de7362951ec5bf3d40fa02de7175552?s=17.600000381469727&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" alt="AncientSwordRage" title="AncientSwordRage"></div>
          <div class="username moderator owner"><span style="float:right">&nbsp;♦</span>AncientSwordRage</div>
        </div>
        <div class="avatar avatar-32 clear-both" style="display: none;"><img width="32" height="32" src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/6de7362951ec5bf3d40fa02de7175552?s=35.20000076293945&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" alt="AncientSwordRage" title="AncientSwordRage">
          <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="username moderator owner" style="display: none;">AncientSwordRage&nbsp;♦</div>
        <div class="flair" title="138197" style="display: none;">138k</div>
      </a>
      <div class="messages">
        <snip>
      </div>
      <div class="clear-both" style="height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

And in the `present-users` list on the right:

```html
    <li class="present-user user-container user-28560" id="present-user-28560" style="opacity: 0.15;">
      <div class="avatar"><img class="user-gravatar32" width="32" height="32" alt="AncientSwordRage" title="AncientSwordRage" src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/6de7362951ec5bf3d40fa02de7175552?s=35.20000076293945&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG"></div><span class="data"><span class="last-activity-time">1640146579</span></span>
    </li>
```

But in the popover when clicking on one of these, you don't get any alt text for the avatar (this is the original one I grabbed for smokie, not mine as have been used previously):

```html
    <div class="popup user-popup" style="left: 86px; top: 263.727px; overflow: visible;">
      <div class="btn-close">X</div>
      <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="/users/120914/smokedetector" style="float: left;">
        <div class="hat" style="float: left; display: block; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: visible; position: absolute; left: 46px; top: 19px;" data-hatid="9829320"><img src="data:image/svg+xml,<snip>" width="28" height="27" style="display: block;">
        </div>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cmCt.png?s=64&amp;g=1" class="user-gravatar48" style="">
      </a>
      <h4 class="username" title="741">SmokeDetector</h4><img width="16" height="16" src="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/softwarerecs/Img/favicon.ico" class="small-site-logo" alt="Software Recommendations" title="Software Recommendations"><br style="clear:both;">
      <p>I'm a bot. Ping some folks in /rooms/11540 with concerns.</p>
      <div class="last-dates">seen <b>16s ago</b>, talked <b>9m ago</b></div>
      <snip>
    </div>
```

No where does this chunk of the document give an alt text for the user which, if not an accessibility issue, is inconsistent with the other bits.